# Amazon DynamoDB & IAM - Allow update-item to change a single attribute

Tags: java, android, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

**Description:**

I have a table with 50 items, each item has at least three attributes `Name`, `Age` and `E-mail`.

The user should be able to:

1. Perform `update` on a specific item's `Name`.
2. Perform these operations on all items' attributes:

- BatchGetItem
- ConditionCheckItem
- DescribeTable
- GetItem
- Scan
- ListTagsOfResource
- Query

**What I've Tried:**

I used this policy in IAM:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "UserNameUpdate",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account>:table/<tableName>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:ReturnValues": [
                        "NONE",
                        "UPDATED_OLD",
                        "UPDATED_NEW"
                    ]
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "dynamodb:Attributes": "Name"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:ConditionCheckItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:ListTagsOfResource",
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account>:table/<tableName>"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The Result:**

- When trying to update-item I get `AccessDeniedException`.
- When trying to other operations they work normally.

I'm not very much into IAM rules, especially `Condition` section . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using StringLike and not StringEquals if you know the exact name of the attribute?

Comment: I am trying `StringLike` because it's more lenient. `StringEquals` was my first choice, but neither worked, I'm getting the same Exception...

Answer (score 1):

`Name` is a [reserved word](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) in DynamoDB.  Perhaps that's your problem?

Comment: That's a good point, I haven't payed attention to this before. But it's the same since I don't use expressions as stated in documentation: `Do not use any of these words as attribute names in expressions`.

Comment: Dang, was hoping that was your problem!  Looking forward to hearing the answer to this question, as I'm just getting into defining IAM policies myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think an array of values is expected:

```
"ForAllValues:StringLike": {
    "dynamodb:Attributes": ["Name"]
}
```